# Inner join with the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have this DB based on orders, split by products (if an order had 2 products, then there are 2 rows with the same transaction code but different products). It records when a product was acquired and when it was sold (basically, when it got in and when it got out). The cost of the product is correct only when it was acquired (a system problem messes with cost when product is sold).

I want to build a query with the following columns:

1. Transaction code (only selling orders)
2. Cost of the product when it was acquired - grouped by transaction code (one row for each transaction).

Can you help me with that? There is a column that states if the transaction was an acquisition or sale, so it can be used.

So basically: "server, bring me the selling transactions, and sum the cost of the products related to it, but their acquisition cost"

Comment: Give some sample data

Comment: And just how would you have one row per transaction with product cost if there is more than 1 product.  Show table design and sample data.  Add desired output.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing, but worth a try:

```
SELECT transaction_id, sum(product_cost) AS cost
  FROM table
  WHERE flag = acquisition
  GROUP BY transaction_id
```